# Help! Flash cannot load XML data from a third-party domain

Tags: xml, flash, rss, actionscript-2, data-access

I am getting news from Yahoo using an RSS feed, using:

```
XML.load("http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/topstories")
```

Yea [this is legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395291/display-stocks-data-from-google-finance-or-yahoo-finance/401546#401546) and all, and although it works perfectly when my SWF is offline -- it shows a security error, but I allow my D drive "domain" in the Adobe [Security Panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html).

But as soon as I upload it to my server, and test it online:

- In Firefox3 the data fails to load, giving me a message on the status bar *"Transferring data from finance.yahoo.com"*
- In InternetExplorer7 it fails silently with no message or warning.

Whats happening? I've even put a [crossdomain.xml](http://www.moock.org/asdg/technotes/crossDomainPolicyFiles/) file with a * wildcard (allowing all domains).

Comment: Some more depressing news here:   http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_14213

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need a subdomain at Yahoo to access this.

**http://finance.yahoo.com/crossdomain.xml**

```
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*.yahoo.com"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="us.js2.yimg.com"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

A quick walk-around is to set up a **proxy-script** on your own server. There's a lot of examples out there. Haven't tried this but the guy wrote it for the same reason as you :

http://www.abdulqabiz.com/blog/archives/general/php_proxy_script_for.php

Comment: Yeah great idea. So I'll just send a memo to the Yahoo Finance HOD asking him to "lend" me a subdomain indefinitely!

Comment: :) the proxy is probably cheaper... I use this method a lot, so should be fine, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your crossdomain.xml ... Actually adding it on your site has no effect, you have to ask Yahoo to put it on their domain :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly is wrong here, you need to give me some more details I think.

I highly recommend you read this completely.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/fplayer8_security.html

Also, a cross domain is only applicable to the domain you are requesting *to* not *from*.

It may also help you to install Fiddler

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Or Charles

http://www.charlesproxy.com/

This will allow you better http debugging.  My guess is that you have a conflicting security sandbox behavior.